# Does the INIWAV tag in VASP assume that the wavefunctions are plane waves?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, orbitals

I am trying to figure out how to set the initial wavefunction in VASP, on the [VASP wiki page of INIWAV](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/INIWAV), it is said that VASP would fill wavefunction arrays with random numbers.

```
INIWAV=1
Fill wavefunction arrays with random numbers.
```

Does `INIWAV=1` mean the occupation number of each wavefunction orbital is random?

Comment: I am assuming this refers to random coefficients of planewaves etc, but admittedly I don't know enough to properly answer.  I suspect someone will know exactly what this really does.

Comment: I also believe that INIWAV = 1 assigns random coefficients on the wavefunctions. Occupancy of orbitals should be controlled by other tags, like ISMEAR, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it randomly chooses the different plane-wave coefficients $c_{Gbk}$ for wavevector $G$, of each trial Kohn-Sham state at each band $b$ and k-point $k$,

$\psi_{bk}(r)=\sum_G c_{gbk}e^{iG.r}$.

The occupation of those states, $f_{bk}$, will be chosen differently. In fact, in a non-self-consistent method, the initial occupations are not important, since they are only used in constructing the output density,

$\rho_{out}(r)=\sum_{bk}f_{bk}|\psi_{bk}(r)|^2,$

at which point the trial eigenvalues are known and the occupations may be assigned following the Fermi-level search and pseudo-thermal occupation.